# How to connect to my VM and host without Ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vmware-player

I am using VMWare player on Ubuntu to run a CentOS VM. I usually connect to it using Bridged and an Ethernet connection and specify a static ip for the VM. How would I connect to my VM without an Ethernet connection?

Comment: if you mean that you don't have an eth0 on your host, the guest can use the lo interface as it's bridge point and you can add a route.

Comment: how would you go about adding a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware or any other virtualization solution should allow you to connect a VNC client to the console.  If I recall correctly, you have to use VMware's management software to do this.

Comment: I can do that. If I don't want to use VNC and instead want to ssh in from a terminal, can I do that?

Comment: Not with VMware AFAIK.  KVM claims it can pipe a virtual serial console to a tty, but I haven't had much luck actually getting it to work. Xen does this all day every day.